# Core Data and Race Conditions

Tags: ios, multithreading, ipad, core-data, race-condition

Question: how do I make Core Date merge changes made to the same `NSManagedObject` in two different threads? The threads change different attributes, and any combination of these attributes is valid.

There is an application with (at least) two threads, the *UI thread* and the *background thread*.
A so-called `Document` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.
A `Document` has three attributes, `attrA`, `attrB` and `attrC`.

The *background thread* reads `attrA` and writes `attrB`, like:

```
doc.attbB = md5(doc.attrA);
```

(in practice, it is more complex and more time-consuming, but you get the idea).

The *UI thread* shows all `attrA`, `attrB` and `attrC` to the user and allows the user to change `attrA` and `attrC`. (And for some while the value of `attrB` is invalid.)

I underline that only *UI thread* writes to `attrA`, and only *background thread* writes to `attrB`.

Now, the user changes `attrC` before calculation of `attrB` is complete.
The *background thread* tries to save `attrB` and gets an error.
What I did for now is:

```
if(!saved) {
    // I did try to check that it's *that* kind of error,
    // but that's iOS5-specific, while I need 4.3
    // (comments on error type checking in 4.3 are welcome).
    // Anyway, finally it was this:
    id tmp = doc.attrB;
    [[doc managedObjectContext] refreshObject:doc mergeChanges:NO];
    doc.attrB = tmp;
    BOOL saved = [context save:&error];
    // NSLog if it still failed
}
```

In the general case this will not work.

At first, what happens if more changes will be made between these lines:

```
    [[doc managedObjectContext] refreshObject:doc mergeChanges:NO];
    doc.attrB = tmp;
    // more changes happen here!!!
    BOOL saved = [context save:&error];
```

Yes, I could replace if by a while, but it's not the general case solution. If the changes happen repeatedly, this may be an endless loop.

At second, the *UI thread* is also may be trying to save something. In one of the classes I see the code intended to merge changes,

```
#pragma mark Changes Propagation

- (void)__contextDidSave:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [parent performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(__mergeChanges:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)__mergeChanges:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [objectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    if (parent) {
        [parent __mergeChanges:notification];
    }
}
```

As I understand, `__mergeChanges` will be run on the right thread, but not immediately; it is possible that the *UI thread* will be trying to save changes in `attrA` and `attrC` after the *background thread* changed `attrB` but before `__mergeChanges` is run.

This is a classic race condition.

Question: how do I **correctly** make Core Date merge changes made to the same `NSManagedObject` in two different threads? (The threads change different attributes, and any combination of these attributes is valid, but Core Data does not know that.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in core data but as I guess you can use the synchronized directive:

```
// UI Thread
@synchronized(AN_INSTANCE_OF_ANY_OBJECT) {
    // your first thread's code goes here
}

// Background Thread
@synchronized(THE_SAME_INSTANCE_OF_THE_OBJECT) {
    // your second thread's code goes here
}
```

this should stops the execution of any thread if any other is executing its scope, notice that the instance should be the same, so if you can not access that instance you can use a public static instance which usually helps me do this trick.

Comment: Two different threads have two different `NSManagedObject`s. That is, I cannot use them for locking. That is, I will need a global lock. At second, what will be the scope? Unless I miss something, it looks like wrapping a save into `@synchronized` will not do any good. And how do I wrap a notification into `@synchronized`? There should be a whole chapter on synchronization, but for some reason I cannot find it. I hope it's not because it's not there.